# How to migrate any single mongodb database into various databases for sharding.?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database

I have a mongo database 'db-all'. And i have many collections and i have filled up large number of documents in each collections.

there are 9 collections, in which each collection have a `'shardKey'` field type of `mongoObjectId`.
and one collection is named 'shard', keeps informations of all the 'shardKey' generated so far with a particular name.

Please note, So far sharding has not been implemented, and this single database has very large number of documents.

Now i want to implement sharding on the basis of 'shardKey'. Such i want to create as many as number of databases as i have number of 'shardKey's in 'shard' collection. And Each database should have 9 collections with same schema as the base database 'db-all' has.

Then i want to move each document of these 9 collections in a new database as per their shardKey in a collection named same it had earlier in 'db-all'.

So, is there any tool available to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using the sharding feature of MongoDB? This is not at all how one goes about it. Start off by reading the [sharding introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/). I'm not sure what the point of the described procedure is...but there'd be no tool available to do it since it doesn't map to any common objective for MongoDB users, as far as I can understand it. It wouldn't be hard anyway since you are just copying documents from one place to another based on a key?